# Что на самом деле входит в структуру MTU в Linux?

Tags: linux, c, сеть, сетевое-программирование

Всем привет, устанавливая MTU в Linux, мы ограничиваем пакеты на отправку и получение, но что входит в это ограничение, в контексте структуры фрейма? Игнорируется ли размер Ethernet Header? При тестировнии, а точнее с помощью команды "ping -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8" мы должны отнимать Ethernet Header и ICMP Header, при дефолтном MTU 1500 (это на отправку), иначе нам сообщит ошибку что нужно меньше нашего дефолтного значения, то есть на отправку проверяется вся длина нашего фрейма включая даже Ethrnet Header. Работает ли это в обратную сторону? То есть, при получении фрейма размером больше 1500,оно откинет его? Или сначала слетят хедера пакетов и только тогда будет смотреться размер? Информация везде часто противоречит сама себе, а описание цисковских IP MTU и Ethernet MTU вообще запутывают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для ограничения приема фрейма существует другое значение MRU. Но оно не устанавливается для ethernet. Нет смысла отбрасывать большие пакеты, ведь они все равно уже пришли и дернули прерывание.

Значение MTU ставится на слой который закрывает то место, на которое вы его ставите. если ставите на эзернет адаптер то считается вместе с заголовком. ведь в адаптер пакет записывается вместе с заголовком эзернет. На ppp интерфейсе будет ip mtu.